# How to avoid a race condition when creating child id based on parent attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Imagine you have a `Site` that has one of those "take a number" thingys, where people take a number, and then wait their turn. Let's say each number is an `Order`. The relationship is that a `Site` has many `Orders`

At a given reset point, the manager of the site goes through and replace the "take a number" thingys with new rolls of numbers, i.e., you can imagine this happening daily. However, the "take a number" thingys are manufacturered with finite numbers, so each roll consists of, let's say 1-100, and then the next roll starts again 100-999.

I'm trying to model the above behavior, how I thought about approaching it:

1. On the `Site` parent, there's a `start_number` attribute. Hitting reset/swapping out the roll, would reset the `start_number` to 100, i.e., the first number of the roll
2. On the `Order` child, there's a callback that assigns a number. If the parent `Site` number is 100, then this means this is the first `Order` since the reset as described in step #1, so then this number is 100 as well. Now, the parent `Site` is auto updated such that it's no longer in a reset state (e.g., `start_number` no longer 100). For future `Orders`, the assigned number is just the next number after the previous order

Here's the code:

```
class Site
  has_many :orders
end

class Order
  belongs_to :site

  before_save :assign_number

  def assign_number
    if site.start_number == 100
      self.number = 100
      self.site.update_column(:start_number, nil)
    else
      self.number = self.site.orders.where.not(number:nil).last.number + 1
    end
  end
end
```

But this is crappy, because unlike with real world "take a number" thingy, 2 orders could get processed at the same time, there is NOT a `unique` constraint on `Order.number` because the numbers do get reused (the roll gets reset). But, it's obviously not helpful if upon reset, 2 orders that get placed close together are both `100`. You only want multiple orders to share a `number` if there truly has been a reset event, not just coincidental timing.

Another problem with this approach is when 1 order is closely followed by a second. Example, let's say the last number assigned was `415`, 2 orders come in fast succession. The first is assigned `416`, the second is so close, that `self.site.orders.where.not(number:nil).last.number` still returns `415` (i.e., `416` hasn't saved yet), and so the second order is now also assigned `416`.

Would be great to get ideas on how to better model the desired behavior. Thanks!

**UPDATE** Per @Fernand's comments, I am going to go with a pessimistic lock, which I'm implementing per notes [here](http://thelazylog.com/understanding-locking-in-rails-activerecord/). So right now code looks like:

```
  def assign_number
    site = self.site.lock!
    if site.start_number == 100
      self.number = 100
      site.start_number = nil
    else
      last_order = self.site.orders.where.not(number:nil).last.lock!
      self.number = last_order.number + 1
      last_order.save! # releases lock
    end
    site.save! #releases lock, whether or not call number was updated to nil
  end
```

I'm not entirely sure how to spec this though... since writing a spec is by definition ordered... how do you force 2 orders to save close together to simulate this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create another table that will store the latest number.

```
#code   :string   not null
#number :bigint   default(0), not null

class Serial < ApplicationRecord
  def self.get_latest_number
    Serial.transaction do
      self.lock.find_or_create_by!(code: 'just_any_identification').increment!(:number).count
    end
  end
end
```

then set the number most probably during callback.

```
class Order
  before_create :set_number #or after_create

  private
    def set_number
      self.number=Serial.get_latest_number if self.number.blank?
    end
end
```

take note of the [transaction lock](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html).

Comment: thanks! updated my question, i am using locks right now, prefer that rater than a new table. any thoughts on how to test this?

Comment: I am not sure how to test this kind of scenario though. Perhaps accepts_nested_attributes_for? Example: Site.new({:order_attributes => {...}}). You should probably post a new question about testing to attract other viewers.